# At what speed is the conservation of angular momentum carried out?

Tags: special-relativity, conservation-laws

If the sun suddenly slowed down would pluto's orbit immediately speed up? If so, then isn't the information pertaining to the sun's angular momentum change being carried to Pluto faster than light?

Would it also suggest that if a massive star in a distant galaxy suddenly slows down every other rotating body in the universe is suddenly aware of this, or is there a locality to the conservation laws that do not class the universe as a closed system?

This leads me to the question: Why isn't the conservation spread out among all spinning bodies, i.e the moon spins round the earth faster as the earths rotation is slowed by friction with the ocean, but why does the moon take on all of the momentum lost, why not spread it out through the whole universe,(if it is one system), which would produce little discernible affect locally?

Please forgive me if this is absolute nonsense but I couldn't get my head around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theory of influences that the question assumes is known as *telekinesis*. Objects arbitrarily act on other objects and transmit their angular momentum (or momentum) to them. But according to physics, telekinesis isn't possible.

An object A may only transfer the angular momentum (or ordinary momentum) to another object B when A exerts torque (or force) on B. The torque (or force) is *exactly the same thing* as the transfer of the angular momentum (or momentum) on the other body. When the torque (or force) is absent, there can't be any transfer so there can't be any slowdown of the object A or acceleration of the object B.

The overall angular momentum carried by the Sun – in the form of its internal spinning – is conserved. If one wants to transfer this angular momentum to another object, one needs a particular "mechanism" that connects the Sun with the object. The tidal forces have this effect but the magnitude of this effect is extremely tiny. One could connect the Sun and Pluto by a metallic construction, or something like that. This could create torque and transfer the angular momentum. But without a mechanism like that, there won't be any transfer.

So the Sun's (or Earth's) spinning just can't slow down with no tangible reason. This is what the conservation of the angular momentum actually says for the Sun! The angular momentum (and similarly the momentum) can never uncontrollably and invisibly dissipate to distant corners of the Universe.

Comment: Thank you, I have a better understanding now of the direct connection that needs to be evident for the effect. However, the speed of the influence still is puzzling. Say we had the following hypothetical setup: A planet that had a moon orbiting it a great distance away but that still had an influence on the planets ocean that slowed it down. In an instant an event happens on the planet that converts ice to water making the oceans deeper, instantly increasing the friction and slowing the planet. Say the moon is 6 light minutes away, how soon before it starts to speed up?

Comment: Sorry, Paul, but your event won't transfer any significant angular momentum to a distant moon. Water in the oceans has viscosity but the momentum and angular momentum are conserved - within the Earth - when the friction slows things down. I think that you are imagining that the moon is needed for the Earth to work or allowed to have the liquid ocean but that's just not the case. Forget about the moon. The Earth may freeze or melt or whatever and its angular momentum and momentum will still be conserved!

Comment: The reason that tidal forces slow the spinning down is a very subtle and weak effect. The Moon is showing the same half to the Earth because it has "adapted" to the tidal forces. When it was spinning  - showing different parts to the Earth - at the beginning, its shape was deforming back and forth, and energy was spent to do so. The Moon acted against this external force trying to squeeze it and stretch it all the time. Such slowing down takes place whenever orbiting bodies spin around their axes but it's a weak effect.

Comment: Gravity of any sort is changed by the speed of light, according to general relativity. But it's virtually impossible to measure this delay because e.g. the Moon-Earth distance is about 1 light second. It takes one second for the influence to propagate but the fields only change by a negligible amount in 1 second - the orbit and even the day (spin of Earth) take much longer. If the delay were significant, you would need to solve detailed equations of general relativity. Also, gravitational waves emitted by the pair could become substantial etc.

Answer (score 1):

The sun (or any body) can't just "slow down" - there has to be a torque applied. And whatever is applying the torque gets the additional angular momentum. That is how conservation of angular momentum works - there is no "magic at a distance".